# Overloading algebraic operators in CRTP class as free functions and return common type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, crtp, type-deduction

my objective is to write a vector and matrix class. For the matrix class I need a specialization for the 2D case. So I decided to inherit specialized classes from a MatrixBase class. What I also want is easy implementation of generic algebra with all derived matrix classes.

To be more precise: I want the Matrix classes to work as my Vector class. My Vector class overloads its operators as non-member functions like this (a Vector multiplied with a scalar):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const Vector<T1> &v1, const T2 s2) {
    Vector<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type> v(v1.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
        v.get(i) = v1.get(i) * s2;

    return v;
};
```

I do it outside because I want left and right side handling and to return a vector of common type.

Now, my Matrix base class is implemented like this, so I can inherit all functionality to the derived classes (just like the copy and move assignment).

```
template<size_t N, typename T, typename Derived>
class Matrix{
public:

    const Derived& operator=(const Derived &other);
    const Derived& operator=(Derived &&other);
};
```

Now, how can I achieve the same functionality as the vector implementation? Meaning, return an object of class Derived, but with underlying common type of a Matrix2D and a scalar T2?

The problem is that as member operator, I can only get right hand multiplication. With a free operator, I can't return the Derived class. And as a friend operator, I would return a Derived object which has the type T and not the common type from the multiplication?

Does anyone have suggestions?

**Edit:** So I haven't found any solution to the core problem yet. I solved the left and right operation by:

```
template<size_t N, typename T, typename Derived>
class Matrix{
public:
  Derived operator*(const T& s) const;
  friend Derived operator*(const T& left, const Derived& right){
    return right*left;
  }
};
```

This solution is derived from: http://kaba.hilvi.org/pastel-1.5.0/restrict_deduction.htm
Although I do not fully understand the Identity class he uses in this blog, since it works fine like this.

Regarding the common type return class, I still do not know how to return a Derived class with underlying type T, which is different from the current object (inheritance is kind of not allowing this, because I have no access?!). I have also read, that (even) the eigen library (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) **requires** operations on common types. So is it even possible?

For example, with the Vector class, this works:

```
int main(){
  Vector<int> vec(5);
  auto vecMul = vec*0.5;
  std::cout << "The type is: \t"<< typeid(vecMul[0]).name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

it returns:

```
The type is:      d
```

Comment: If mutiple classes inherit `Matrix<N, common_type, ...>`, which one do you want to return?

Comment: @xskxzr I am not sure what you are asking. For now, I have `class MatrixND<N,T> : public Matrix<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>` and `class MatrixND<2,T> : public Matrix<2,T,MatrixND<2,T>>`. But my actual concern is in the base class, if `Derived` is (for example) of type `MatrixND<2,int>` and is multiplied by type `double`, I want to return a type `MatrixND<2,double>`. Was that it?

Comment: I mean if there is another `class Another_MatrixND : public Matrix<2, double, Another_MatrixND>`, why do you choose to return `MatrixND<2,double>` instead of `Another_MatrixND`. Note `Matrix` does not know `Derived` is a specialization of a template.

Comment: If **only** `MatrixND<N,T>` inherit `Matrix<N,T,...>`, why not simply use `Matrix<N,T>` without CRTP?

Comment: One reason is to just use crtp as practice, the second is code replication, right? If I only use `MatrixND` and specialize it, I would need to copy paste common functionality, wouldn't I?! I get now, what you are saying, but then, does it matter in that case? Once I implemented `Vector`, I started Matrix using crtp, so I might want to include Vector as specialization of MatrixND as well and came to that question. But now, that I am thinking about it(based on your suggestion), I might want to just use the same syntax I used for `Vector` where I implemented the derived classes and not in base